# How can a JSON call another JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am developing a simple application with AngularJS and I want to get the value of the price dynamically so I want to make a JSON call to another JSON and I am not sure if is this possible !

This is my data.json:

```
[{
        "name": "city A",
        "elements": [{
          "id": "c01",
          "name": "name1",
          "price": "15",
          "qte": "10"
        }, {
          "id": "c02",
          "name": "name2",
          "price": "18",
          "qte": "11"
        }, {
          "id": "c03",
          "name": "name3",
          "price": "11",
          "qte": "14"
        }],
        "subsities": [{
          "name": "sub A1",
          "elements": [{
            "id": "sub01",
            "name": "nameSub1",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "14"
          }, {
            "id": "sub02",
            "name": "nameSub2",
            "price": "8",
            "qte": "13"
          }, {
            "id": "sub03",
            "name": "nameSub3",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "14"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "sub A2",
          "elements": [{
            "id": "ssub01",
            "name": "nameSsub1",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "7"
          }, {
            "id": "ssub02",
            "name": "nameSsub2",
            "price": "8",
            "qte": "1"
          }, {
            "id": "ssub03",
            "name": "nameSsub3",
            "price": "4",
            "qte": "19"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "sub A3",
          "elements": [{
            "id": "sssub01",
            "name": "nameSssub1",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "11"
          }, {
            "id": "sssub02",
            "name": "nameSssub2",
            "price": "2",
            "qte": "15"
          }, {
            "id": "sssub03",
            "name": "nameSssub3",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "15"
          }]
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "city B",
        "elements": [{
          "id": "cc01",
          "name": "name11",
          "price": "10",
          "qte": "11"
        }, {
          "id": "cc02",
          "name": "name22",
          "price": "14",
          "qte": "19"
        }, {
          "id": "cc03",
          "name": "name33",
          "price": "11",
          "qte": "18"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "city C",
        "elements": [{
          "id": "ccc01",
          "name": "name111",
          "price": "19",
          "qte": "12"
        }, {
          "id": "ccc02",
          "name": "name222",
          "price": "18",
          "qte": "17"
        }, {
          "id": "ccc03",
          "name": "name333",
          "price": "10",
          "qte": "5"
        }]
      }]
```

And I want to get the value of price from this url : [url json](http://total.smarteez.eu/submit/?station=114237)

I want to do something like :

```
[{
            "name": "city A",
            "elements": [{
              "id": "c01",
              "name": "name1",
              "price": "prix_diesel",/*prix_diesel is an attribute in json url I want to extract its value here.*/
              "qte": "10"
            }, {
              "id": "c02",
              "name": "name2",
              "price": "18",
              "qte": "11"
            }, {
              "id": "c03",
              "name": "name3",
              "price": "11",
              "qte": "14"
            }],
            "subsities": [{
              "name": "sub A1",
              "elements": [{
                "id": "sub01",
                "name": "nameSub1",
                "price": "1",
                "qte": "14"
              }, {
                "id": "sub02",
                "name": "nameSub2",
                "price": "8",
                "qte": "13"
              }, {
                "id": "sub03",
                "name": "nameSub3",
                "price": "1",
                "qte": "14"
              }]
            }, {
              "name": "sub A2",
              "elements": [{
                "id": "ssub01",
                "name": "nameSsub1",
                "price": "1",
                "qte": "7"
              }, {
                "id": "ssub02",
                "name": "nameSsub2",
                "price": "8",
                "qte": "1"
              }, {
                "id": "ssub03",
                "name": "nameSsub3",
                "price": "4",
                "qte": "19"
              }]
            }, {
              "name": "sub A3",
              "elements": [{
                "id": "sssub01",
                "name": "nameSssub1",
                "price": "1",
                "qte": "11"
              }, {
                "id": "sssub02",
                "name": "nameSssub2",
                "price": "2",
                "qte": "15"
              }, {
                "id": "sssub03",
                "name": "nameSssub3",
                "price": "1",
                "qte": "15"
              }]
            }]
          }
           ......
           ......
            ]
```

I set this up in my plunkr : [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/i3UPTW99RFRFZ8E6NuZq?p=preview)

I search and I found that if I want to get the data from the URL, I'll need an XMLHttpRequest (with Angular, I can use $http.get). But here I am using a JSON which call another JSON file so how can I resolve this problem ? do you have any idea please !

Comment: No it is not possible. When you assign to a variable you can do 
`var price = {"prix": {"prix_diesel": "8.25", "prix_essence": "10.14", "prix_aditive": "8.80"}}; var list = { ..., "price": parseFloat(price.prix_diesel)}`

Answer (score 3):

You can't. JSON is not a programming language but an open standard for data transfer.

What you can do however is reference an object from the second file in the first file. An example:

```
[{
    "name": "city A",
    "elements": [{
        "id": "c01",
        "name": "name1",
        "price": "prix_diesel",
        "qte": "10"
    }]
    // Simplified
}]
```

And the JSON from your URL:

```
{
    "prix": {
        "prix_diesel": "8.25",
        "prix_essence": "10.14",
        "prix_aditive": "8.80"
    }
}
```

Now write a JS function which finds the reference in your first JSON file `prix_diesel` and look up the value of that key in the JSON from the url `8.25`.

An example would be similar to this:

```
for (var element of myJson.elements) {
    var reference = element.price; // prix_diesel
    var referenceValue = jsonFromUrl.prix[reference]; // 8.25
}
```

This will find all the prices of your elements based on their reference (which is actually just the name of a key in your second JSON).

---

A side note, I noticed the JSON from your URL is supposed to be protected by login functionality. However, like you demonstrate in your own post, with the correct endpoints the data is easily accessible without needing to log in. If this is a product you own and you don't want this data to be publically available I'd suggest looking into a solution to prevent non-logged in users from requesting data. Have a look at [passportjs.org](http://passportjs.org).

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer please can you set this up in a  plunker

Answer (score 0):

i forked your plunker (changed your data.json too)

after loading second json you can get it like(code is something like "prix_diesel". it is in updated json)

```
function getPrice(code){
        return priceData.prix[code];
      }
```

[updated](http://plnkr.co/edit/USSypg?p=preview)